# Conditional dplyr::summarize() of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

In my `DATA` below, I wonder how to `summarize()` the number of 6 different Ethnicities (`Hispanic`, `AmIndian`, `Asian`, `White`, `Pacific`, `AsiaPacific`) chosen (`"Y"`) when `Ethinc_overall!="B"`?

```
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- read.table(h=TRUE,text=
"EL_Type Language Black Hispanic AmIndian Asian White Pacific AsiaPacific Ethinc_overall
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     Y     N       N           Y              M
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     Y       N           N              M
 Current  English Black        N    Y     N     N       N           N              M
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     Y     N       N           Y              M
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     N       Y           Y              H
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     N     N       Y           Y              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    Y     Y     Y       Y           Y              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     Y       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        Y    N     N     N       N           N              H
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     Y       N           N              M
 Current  English Black        N    N     N     N       N           N              B")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can summarize across the wanted columns by group, and then convert the results from wide to long format:

```r
DATA %>% 
  filter(Ethinc_overall != "B") %>% 
  summarise(across(Hispanic:AsiaPacific, 
                   list(Y = ~ sum(. == "Y"))), .by = Ethinc_overall) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Ethinc_overall, values_to = "count") %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("ethnicity", "Y")) %>% 
  # filter(count > 0) %>% 
  select(-Y)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    Ethinc_overall ethnicity   count
#>    <chr>          <chr>       <int>
#>  1 H              Hispanic       23
#>  2 H              AmIndian        8
#>  3 H              Asian           1
#>  4 H              White           9
#>  5 H              Pacific         3
#>  6 H              AsiaPacific     3
#>  7 M              Hispanic        0
#>  8 M              AmIndian        1
#>  9 M              Asian           2
#> 10 M              White           2
#> 11 M              Pacific         0
#> 12 M              AsiaPacific     2
```

or better, start with `pivot_longer` and then `summarise`:

```r
DATA %>% 
  filter(Ethinc_overall != "B") %>% 
  pivot_longer(Hispanic:AsiaPacific, names_to = "ethnicity") %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(value =="Y"), .by = c(Ethinc_overall, ethnicity))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    Ethinc_overall ethnicity   count
#>    <chr>          <chr>       <int>
#>  1 H              Hispanic       23
#>  2 H              AmIndian        8
#>  3 H              Asian           1
#>  4 H              White           9
#>  5 H              Pacific         3
#>  6 H              AsiaPacific     3
#>  7 M              Hispanic        0
#>  8 M              AmIndian        1
#>  9 M              Asian           2
#> 10 M              White           2
#> 11 M              Pacific         0
#> 12 M              AsiaPacific     2
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the folowing code to count only occurrences of `"Y"`:

```
DATA %>% filter(Ethinc_overall!="B") %>% 
    summarise_at(c('Hispanic', 'AmIndian', 'Asian', 'White', 'Pacific','AsiaPacific'),
                 function(x){sum(x=="Y")})
```

Explanation:

- `filter(Ethinc_overall!="B")` - discards all rows for which value in
  column `Ethinc_overall` is equal to `B`
- `summarise_at(where,what)` - performs some operation (`what`) in given columns (`where`)
- `function(x){sum(x=="Y")}` - it is a function that checks if argument is equal to `"Y"` and sums all `TRUE` values in the column. You can pretty much change the content of the function as you like.

The outcome is:

```
Hispanic    AmIndian    Asian   White   Pacific AsiaPacific
  <int>       <int>     <int>   <int>     <int>     <int>
    23          9         3       11        3          5
```

Comment: `summarise_at` has been superseded by `sumarise(across())`. We can do this ```DATA %>% filter(Ethinc_overall!="B") %>% summarise(across(Hispanic:AsiaPacific, list(~sum(.x == "Y"))))```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but maybe this does what you're trying to do (you can replace `summarise` by `mutate` depending on the resulting object you prefer):

```
DATA |> 
  dplyr::summarise(
    across(
      .cols = c(Hispanic, AmIndian, Asian, White, Pacific, AsiaPacific),
      .fns = list(
        counted =  ~length(which(. == "Y" & Ethinc_overall != "B"))
      ),
      .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
    ))

## this gives:
##  Hispanic_counted AmIndian_counted Asian_counted White_counted Pacific_counted AsiaPacific_counted
##1               23                9             3            11               3                   5
```